# How to update changed date for a node

Tags: 8, migrations

I am migrating content from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8. Migration works fine except the changed date for node get changed to the current time. I want to set the timestamp to the Drupal 7 timestamp. I have tried out the following but it is not working.

```
        $changed_date = $node->getChangedTime();
        $node->set($source['parent_field_name'], $paragraph_target);
        $node->changed->value = $changed_date;
        // print_r($changed_date);die;
        $node->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not personally tested, but according [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2329253#comment-13904064) is a problem for already existing entities, while it should be resolved for new ones.
Also, there's a [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/preserve_changed) that seems to address this issue.
So, I'd say:

1. try to create the node only in one step, to see if that preserve the original timestamp
2. if that fails, try either the patch or the module

Comment: Thanks.... the module on;y works for non-translated content... When I add it for translated content the module doesn't work.